# How to create callback function of a uicontrol object which calls the handle object

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have defined an uicontrol pushbutton object and I want to display something in handles when I click on the button. When I try to do that, I get the error `Undefined function or variable 'handles'`. It does not see the handles or any other object which is in GUI code.

```
handles.c = 3;
A = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton');
A.Callback = display(handles.c)
```

This code gives the error that I typed above. I may have to give the handle object to the Callback as input but I don't know how to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The callback should be a function - `A.Callback = @(varargin) display(handles.c);`. Note this will only ever display `3` because that's what the value is when the function is defined, so it's then treated as static.

Comment: I want to type an if else block. How can I type more than one seperate lines?

Comment: Write it as a separate function, in its own file or locally in the same file if you have a newer version of MATLAB. Then use `A.Callback = @myFunction`.

Comment: I did this now, but I need to give this function another input. How do I do this? Do varargin gives only objects in gui code? Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: `A.Callback = @(evt, action) myfunction( evt, action, otherInput1, otherInput2 )` will work, read the documentation on `varargin`, it has no specific link with GUIs.

Comment: I could not understand this input order.

Comment: Without [edit]ing your question, I can't read your mind to know why and what you don't understand... Please provide a [mcve] with your expected behaviour, and what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the `handles` data structure often referred to in MATLAB's UI documentation, you have to use [`guidata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) to set new values and retrieve existing values when in a callback.

So from anywhere, if you want to set the value you'll want to do something like:

```
handles.c = 3

% Replace `gcf` with the explicit handle to your figure if possible
guidata(gcf, handles)
```

Then inside of your callback, you can get the current `guidata` the following way:

```
function callback(src, event)
  handles = guidata(src);
  display(handles.c)
end
```

And then assign this function as the callback to your `uicontrol`

```
A = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'Callback', @callback);
```

If you don't want to create a separate callback function and instead insist on a one-liner, you could create an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to accomplish a similar task

```
A.callback = @(src, evnt)display(getfield(guidata(src), 'c'))
```

As you can see, the explicit function is a little easier to understand

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer. One more question: is src handles? if it is, where is hObject over there?

Comment: @sanmiyom Sorry for the confusion. `src` is what GUIDE calls `hObject`, the handle of the control that is triggering the callback. You have to provide a graphics handle to `guidata` to get `handles`